# Display Json formatted input from Flask in python

Tags: python, flask

Trying to take a Json  input from user and display it with proper json formatting:

Below is the python code:

```
@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    return jsonify(request.form)
if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is the html code:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the output:
[image]

What mistake am I doing here to  get the result on the flask page in proper json format ?

This is the output i'm getting:

```
text    "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}"
```

Desired Op:

```
{
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":3
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/output, instead copy and paste the output and paste in a quotation block or code block.

Comment: Can you post the current output please (in a quotation block). It's too blurry to read.

Comment: What are you giving input in the text box?

Comment: input is this {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}

Comment: ive added the output as text,please check now

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the result **is** json(the output is kind of blurry). It just doesn't have all the line breaks.

From what I can see, you are using `flask.jsonify()`. On the API page, under  `flask.json.jsonify(*args, **kwargs)`, it states:

> This function’s response will be pretty printed if the `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` config parameter is set to True or the Flask app is running in debug mode. Compressed (not pretty) formatting currently means no indents and no spaces after separators.

Which means that you need to change the config.  `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` needs to be set to `true`.

Hope that I helped.

Comment: You are use Flask as well, yes?

Comment: That was dumb, I didn't see the part where you mentioned that it was a flask page.

Comment: tried this app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True,but still op is the same